# What does _com_interfaces_ do?

Tags: python, pywin32, shell-extensions, com-server, icon-handler

I'm trying to understand the COM server examples of [pywin32](/questions/tagged/pywin32), and in `win32comext/shell/demos/servers/icon_handler.py` I saw the line

```
_com_interfaces_ = [shell.IID_IExtractIcon, pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile]
```

While that pretty clearly refers to an [`IconHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122(v=vs.85).aspx) having to implement the [`IExtractIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761854(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`IPersistFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687223(v=vs.85).aspx) interfaces, I cannot find any documentation *where* `_com_interfaces_` is actually used. It is nowhere to be seen in `win32com.server.register` or `win32com.server.localserver.py`, so neither registration nor the server call seem to actually use this. Is there any documentation on `_com_interfaces_`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_com_interfaces_` is an optional attribute a [Server Policy](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartServerCom.html#Policies) looks for:

> `_com_interfaces_`
>
> Optional list of IIDs exposed by this object. If this attribute is missing, `IID_IDispatch` is assumed (ie, if not supplied, the COM object will be created as a normal Automation object.

The list is used to answer [`QueryInterface` enqueries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682521(v=vs.85).aspx), see the [`win32com.server.policy` module](https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32/blob/753322f9ac4b943c2c04ddd88605e68bc742dbb4/lib/x64/win32com/server/policy.py) to see how this is being used, specifically the [`BasicPolicy._wrap()`](https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32/blob/753322f9ac4b943c2c04ddd88605e68bc742dbb4/lib/x64/win32com/server/policy.py#L207) and  [`BasicPolicy._QueryInterface_`](https://github.com/SublimeText/Pywin32/blob/753322f9ac4b943c2c04ddd88605e68bc742dbb4/lib/x64/win32com/server/policy.py#L247) methods.

Comment: I see, thanks. That leads me to `win32com.server.policy` which explains a bit more about Policies and Dispatchers

Comment: Slightly related, but `comtypes`: https://svn.python.org/projects/ctypes/branches/comtypes-0.4/docs/com_interfaces.txt